# Popover não funciona quando adicionado dinamicamente por jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, popover

Tenho uma div com diversa informação e um popover (Bootflat).

Quando adiciono via jquery outra div igual, o novo popover da nova div não funciona. (a div fica com a formatação correta e o código do popover também fica correto)

Abaixo,o 1º tr já está na página, o 2º tr é adicionado dinamicamente via jQuery.

```
<tr id="36" class="remove-runner ">
<th scope="row">aaa bbb
    <div class="checkpoint_options_hor tooltip-demo">
        <i class="info_runner glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" title="" data-container="body" data-html="true" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="<b> tyet:</b> UYT GGH<br /> <b>Esc:</b> M40<br /> <b>Estado:</b> Terminou<br /> " data-original-title="Run XPTO"></i> <i id="star_36" class="favorite_star glyphicon glyphicon-star" onclick="favoriteRunner(this, 36)" data-original-title="Add Runner fav" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"></i>
    </div>
</th>
<td data-title="P G">12º</td>
<td data-title="P S">13º</td>
<td data-title="P E">4º</td>                            
<td data-title="9k">1:20:55</td>
<td data-title="45k">6:56:42</td>
<td data-title="7k">14:51:59</td>
<td data-title="12k">28:57:39</td>
<td data-title="152k">39:08:31</td>
<td data-title="Meta">46:49:16</td>
<td>
    <a class="tooltip-demo">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-remove cursor_pointer" data-original-title="Remover atleta" data-toggle="tooltip" onclick="deleteDivCompare(this)" data-placement="left"></i>
    </a>
</td>
```

```
<tr id="41" class="remove-runner">
<th scope="row">UTGG Tggb
    <div class="checkpoint_options_hor tooltip-demo">
        <i class="info_runner glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" title="" data-container="body" data-html="true" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="<b> yhuh:</b> <br /> <b>Esc:</b> SEsaM<br /> <b>Estado:</b> Finisher<br /> " data-original-title="Iujh YGAG"></i> <i id="star_41" class="favorite_star glyphicon glyphicon-star" onclick="favoriteRunner(this, 41)" data-original-title="Add Fav" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"></i>
    </div>
</th>
<td data-title="P G">12º</td>
<td data-title="P S">12º</td>
<td data-title="P E">7º</td>
<td data-title="9k">1:33:32</td>
<td data-title="4k">7:55:35</td>
<td data-title="79k">15:55:46</td>
<td data-title="125k">28:57:26</td>
<td data-title="15k">39:48:15</td>
<td data-title="Me">46:23:26</td>
<td>
    <a class="tooltip-demo">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-remove cursor_pointer" data-original-title="Remover atleta" data-toggle="tooltip" onclick="deleteDivCompare(this)" data-placement="left"></i>
    </a>
</td>
```

Código jQuery para adicionar o 2º

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'post',
    url : 'folder/classXPTO.php',
    dataType : 'html',
    data : {
        id_xpto : id
    },
    beforeSend : function() {
    },
    complete : function() {
    },
    success : function(options) {
```

/* options is the code html received by PHP */
                $('.tbody').append(options);

```
    },
    error : function(xhr, er) {
```

...
        }
    });

O que posso fazer para corrigir isto?

Comment: O valor dessa id `id="star_44"` é único?

Comment: Coloque o código que habilita a popover, provavelmente é só um erro de referencia.

Comment: poste a parte em que faz a chamada dos arquivos jquery e bootstrap

Comment: Já adicionei o código HTML e javascript para adicionar dinamicamente

Comment: impossível testar seu código para ver aonde está o erro, você colou um modelo e não o script. dessa forma não tenho como ajudar. copie e cole  no seu editor o código que passou ele não vai executar nada, cole o que você fez.